# Azure SQL monitoring high DTU

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

We're getting spikes from time to time but can't find what causes it.

- How to monitor the Azure SQL DTU usage?
- How can I find what are the high DTU queries in live?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following will show you a log of the 100 most recent DTU logs. As of now, a log entry is created every 15 seconds.

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats
ORDER BY end_time DESC
```

Comment: What database or version of SQL server is this? I cannot find the table.

Comment: @Triynko: This works for my databases, which are running on Sql Azure v12. The database is specified in the query: [sys]

Comment: is there a nice way to get 'nulls' from this query if it doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

Please have a check on the below links which talks about Azure SQL Database Throughput Unit (DTU).

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/11/azure-sql-database-introduces-new-near-real-time-performance-metrics/

[Azure SQL Database "DTU percentage" metric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906628/azure-sql-database-dtu-percentage-metric)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn741336.aspx

Regards,
Mekh.

Comment: You should post the main material in your answer and use the links for reference only.

Comment: Will do the same from now on. Thanks